# Python Pandas: Transpose or Stack?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have an example data frame below.  I am having trouble obtain the desired results through transpose....

```
x = ('P', 'P', 'O', 'DNP', 'D')
y = ('O', 'O', 'D', 'DNP', 'DNP')
z = ('P', 'P', 'O', 'U', 'DNP')
a = ('O', 'O', 'D', 'DNP', 'DNP')
b = ('P', 'DNP', 'O', 'U', 'DNP')
ID = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID5']
df = DataFrame(zip(ID, a, b, x, y, z), columns = ['id', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

    id    a    b    x    y    z
0  ID1    O    P    P    O    P
1  ID2    O  DNP    P    O    P
2  ID3    D    O    O    D    O
3  ID4  DNP    U  DNP  DNP    U
4  ID5  DNP  DNP    D  DNP  DNP
```

A simple df.transpose() produces...

```
0    1    2    3    4
id  ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4  ID5
a     O    O    D  DNP  DNP
b     P  DNP    O    U  DNP
x     P    P    O  DNP    D
y     O    O    D  DNP  DNP
z     P    P    O    U  DNP
```

The desired output is as follows....

```
   ID1    a    O
   ID1    b    P
   ID1    x    P
   ID1    y    O
   ID1    z    P
   ID2    a    O
   ID2    b    DNP
   ID2    x    P
   ID2    y    O
   ID2    z    P
```

and so on and so forth.....  I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
In [23]: pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], var_name='colvals', value_name='DOPU')
Out[23]: 
     id colvals DOPU
0   ID1       a    O
1   ID2       a    O
2   ID3       a    D
...
21  ID2       z    P
22  ID3       z    O
23  ID4       z    U
24  ID5       z  DNP
```

---

Or, alternatively, you could set `id` as the index before calling [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [21]: df.set_index('id').stack()
Out[21]: 
id    
ID1  a      O
     b      P
     x      P
     y      O
     z      P
...         
ID5  a    DNP
     b    DNP
     x      D
     y    DNP
     z    DNP
dtype: object
```

`stack` moves the column level values into the index. Since the desired result
has `id` values in the index as well, it is natural to use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to move
the `id` column into the index first, and then to call `stack`.

---

Call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to move the index levels into DataFrame columns:

```
In [164]: df.columns.name = 'colvals'
In [165]: df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index()
Out[165]: 
     id colvals    0
0   ID1       a    O
1   ID1       b    P
2   ID1       x    P
3   ID1       y    O
4   ID1       z    P
...
20  ID5       a  DNP
21  ID5       b  DNP
22  ID5       x    D
23  ID5       y  DNP
24  ID5       z  DNP
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu,  A lot easier than I thought.  Is there a way to not set the ID column as the index so the desired result will have the ID for every instance?  I want to make the result into a new dataframe.  Thanks!

Comment: @boothtp: Use `reset_index` to move the index levels into (DataFrame) columns.