# how to use column names as values in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas data frame:

```
df = DataFrame({'B' : ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'), 'C' : (1,3,5,6,8,2,5), 'D' : (5,2,6,9,3,7,3)})




    B  C  D
 0  A  1  5
 1  B  3  2
 2  C  5  6
 3  D  6  9
 4  E  8  3
 5  F  2  7
 6  G  5  3
```

I need to make computations excel. The format that would be convenient for me is:

```
    B description  value
0   A           C      1
1   B           C      3
2   C           C      5
3   D           C      6
4   E           C      8
5   F           C      2
6   G           C      5
7   A           D      5
8   B           D      2
9   C           D      6
10  D           D      9
11  E           D      3
12  F           D      7
13  G           D      3
```

is there a way to use the column names as value

Comment: It's unclear how your desired output is generated can you explain this clearly

Comment: basically what I want is to append the values of each column (but B) to the data frame and add one more column that has as values the name of the column associated with each value. I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31910716/190597

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the convenient `pd.melt` for this, see the answer of @unutbu. A more general approach is to use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), but this requires a bit more manual adaptations:

```
In [139]: df.set_index('B').stack().reset_index()
Out[139]:
    B level_1  0
0   A       C  1
1   A       D  5
2   B       C  3
3   B       D  2
4   C       C  5
5   C       D  6
6   D       C  6
7   D       D  9
8   E       C  8
9   E       D  3
10  F       C  2
11  F       D  7
12  G       C  5
13  G       D  3
```

After some renaming and sorting:

```
In [150]: result = df.set_index('B').stack().reset_index()

In [151]: result = result.rename(columns={'level_1':'description', 0:'value'})

In [152]: result.sort(['description', 'B']).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[152]:
    B description  value
0   A           C      1
1   B           C      3
2   C           C      5
3   D           C      6
4   E           C      8
5   F           C      2
6   G           C      5
7   A           D      5
8   B           D      2
9   C           D      6
10  D           D      9
11  E           D      3
12  F           D      7
13  G           D      3
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
In [13]: pd.melt(df, id_vars=['B'], var_name='description')
Out[13]: 
    B description  value
0   A           C      1
1   B           C      3
2   C           C      5
3   D           C      6
4   E           C      8
5   F           C      2
6   G           C      5
7   A           D      5
8   B           D      2
9   C           D      6
10  D           D      9
11  E           D      3
12  F           D      7
13  G           D      3
```